# Update modal jquery box is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, grails

I had a create jquery modal box with validation and its working. But for my update jquery modal box, its not working. The bvalid isnt running the validation as I've tried to submit the form in the cancel button and it works. Let me show you guys the codes.

```
$(function() {
      var username = $( "#username" ),
      email = $( "#email" ),
      password = $( "#password" ),
      accountexpired = $( "#account_expired" ),

      allFields = $( [] ).add( username ).add( email ).add( password ).add( accountexpired ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
      if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
          min + " and " + max + "." );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    $( "#edit1" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 700,
      width: 500,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Update": function() {
             var bValid = true;
             allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

              bValid = bValid && checkLength( username, "Length of username must be between 3 and 16. Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter. ", 3, 16 );
              bValid = bValid && checkLength( email, "Length of email must be between 6 and 80. eg. ui@mail.com", 6, 80 );
              bValid = bValid && checkLength( password, "Length of password must be between 5 and 16. Password field only allow : a-z 0-9", 5, 16 );

              bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( username, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter." );
              bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
              bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );


          if ( bvalid ) {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
              $('#editUser').submit();

          }
        },
        Cancel: function() {

          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }

      }

    });
```

As for the html:

```
<%--Update user box --%>
            <div id="edit1" title="Update user">
                  <form id="editUser" method="post" name="editUser">
                      <p class="validateTips"><g:message code="default.error.requiredforms.message" />.</p>

                        <g:each in="${Query1}">
                <table id="editpage" style="border-collapse: collapse;">

                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="username"><g:message code="default.searchcustomer.username.message" />:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="hidden" name="username" id="username"
                            style="border: 1px solid black" value="${it.username}" /><label>${it.username}</label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="white-space: nowrap"><label for="account_expired"><g:message code="default.searchcustomer.accexpired.message" />:</label></td>
                        <td style="text-align: left"><input type="radio"
                            name="account_expired" id="account_expired" value="${true}"
                            ${it.account_expired == true ? 'checked="checked"' : ''}>
                            True <input type="radio" name="account_expired" id="account_expired" value="${false}"
                            ${it.account_expired == false ? 'checked="checked"' : ''}>
                            False</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="password"><g:message code="default.searchcustomer.password.message" />:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password"
                            style="border: 1px solid black" value="${it.password}" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="email"><g:message code="default.searchcustomer.email.message" />:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"
                            style="border: 1px solid black" value="${it.email}" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    </table>
                    </g:each> 
                            </form>
                  </div>
```

I did implement some ajax into this but I have no idea why the validation is not working and preventing me from submitting the form. Any guys out there can help me with this? Thank you guys so much.

Comment: removeClass() expects a single argument so "tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );" looks wrong. Though I doubt that is what is causing your problems. I tested the bValid bit and all the tests seem to pass for normal input.

Answer (score 0):

Define action in `form`

```
<form id="editUser" method="post" name="editUser" action="">
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are outputting the "editpage" table inside a loop. If more than one is output, you end up with many elements having the same names and ids, which is invalid. When clicking "Update", maybe the validation looks at the first fields having the ids involved, and not the ones you are trying to validate.

All this provided, of course, that `${Query1}` returns more than one row.

If the dialog is removed but the form not submitted when clicking Update, I guess it's also worth trying to submit the form before closing the dialog, though I doubt it would make a difference as closing the dialog just hides it afaik.